# Why won't my output display to the webpage?

Tags: html, node.js, angular, tokenize

[image]My page is just showing:
Tokenized string: {{ inputString | tokenizer:delimiter }}

Its not passing through the values from the input feilds.
I dont see any errors in the consiole.
Nor do I see any errors in the terminal.

part2.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TokenizePipe } from './tokenizer.pipe';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './part2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./part2.component.css'],
})
export class Part2Component {
  inputString = '';
  delimiter = '';
}
```

tokenizer.pipe.ts:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'tokenizer',
})
export class TokenizePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(inputString: string, delimiter = ', '): string {
    if (!inputString) {
      return '';
    }

    return inputString.split('').join(delimiter);
  }
}
```

part2.component.html:

```
<div>
    <label for="inputString">Input string:</label>
    <input id="inputString" [(ngModel)]="inputString" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="delimiter">Delimiter:</label>
    <input id="delimiter" [(ngModel)]="delimiter" />
</div>
<p>Tokenized string: {{ inputString | tokenizer:delimiter }}</p>
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { Part2Component } from './part2.component';
import { TokenizePipe } from './tokenizer.pipe';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    Part2Component,
    TokenizePipe // Declare the TokenizePipe
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [Part2Component]
})
export class AppModule { } // export the AppModule class
```

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of current output?

Comment: @konrad - should be there now. At the top.

Comment: I just tested your code, it's working as expected.